In robotframework, In a group of multiple test cases in a robot file, how can i skip to the last test case
In the below robot file, Is there a way to SKIP to the last Test Case "D Test Validation" based on the SKIP condition in "Test StepA2". This should skip both "B Test Validation" and "C Test Validation" cases completely and move on to "D Test Validation".
*** Test Cases ***
A Test Validation
    Test StepA1
    Test StepA2

B Test Validation
     Test StepB1
     Test StepB2

C Test Validation
     Test StepC1
     Test StepC2

D Test Validation
     Test StepD1
     Test StepD2

PS: SKIP can be used to skip the next set of Test Steps in the Test Case, but what i am looking is more of a "GOTO" concept.
Can this be achieved in robotframework?

Use the package robotframework-dependencylibrary to skip tests B and C if test A is skipped.
*** Settings ***
Library    DependencyLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
A Test Validation
    Test StepA1
    Test StepA2

B Test Validation
     Depends on test   A Test Validation
     Test StepB1
     Test StepB2

C Test Validation
     Depends on test   A Test Validation
     Test StepC1
     Test StepC2

D Test Validation
     Test StepD1
     Test StepD2

Note that with this approach, if A fails, B and C will also be skipped, which may or may not be what you wanted.
